# USMT 5.0, KnownFolderIDs support

Tags: migration, mdt-2012, usmt

Starting to build our customized migdocs config xml, and I am finding that USMT doesn't seem to support the [Known Folder IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx), although [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/04/13/new-usmt-5-0-features-for-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx) seems to indicate that it should fully support them.

> USMT now supports all of the KNOWNFOLDERID types now. Previously some (such as FOLDERID_Links) were not and required some hacking.

Looking through scanstate logs, and it appears that the only Known Folder ID that it is supported is the **Downloads** folder. This is also the only folder that I've seen used in other forum posts. We can use hardcoded paths or (hopefully) CSIDL references, but would like to use KnownFolderID's as they are the replacement for CSIDL, and should be supported.

This is an example of my usage in the MigDocs.xml:

> <pattern type="File">%FOLDERID_ProgramFiles%\FolderName\* [*]</pattern>

If I have this pattern in an exclude, I find that it isn't excluded. If I change this line to:

> <pattern type="File">C:\Program Files\FolderName\* [*]</pattern>

Then it works.

Edit to add information:
 - We're running this in offline mode, in Windows PE (actually, Windows RE from DaRT for Windows 8), and running it against an installation of windows 7.

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a backslash. Try `<pattern type="file">%FOLDERID_ProgramFiles%\FolderName\* [*]</pattern>`. This puts a backslash after FolderName to get everything inside 'FolderName' and all subdirectories. I'm basing this on all the examples from the TechNet article '[How to Include Files and Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824833.aspx)' from the User State Migration Tool (USMT) Technical Reference.

Comment: that didn't come through properly... it won't put the last slash after 'Foldername'. maybe it did the same thing to you and you ARE using that slash?

Comment: Yeah, I have the backslash on the end. I'm fairly confident the syntax is correct, because I can use hardcoded paths or CSIDL vars, but none of the FOLDERID vars seem to work.

Comment: @WinOutreach4 Getting used to Markdown can be rough. Bashing on Markdown is a user theme... FIFY.

Comment: According to the TechNet article '[Recognized Environment Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825266.aspx)', you would not write it as:
%FOLDERID_ProgramFiles%


Rather, you would write it as %ProgramFiles%. There are a few examples of this in the TechNet article '[Custom XML Examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824988.aspx#Example4+)', like this one:
<pattern type="File">%ProgramFiles%\USMTDIRTestFolder\* [*]</pattern>

Comment: From what I can tell, it looks like it's supposed to support both. It supports environment variables (per your link), as well as CSIDL, and is [supposed to support KnownFolderIDs as well.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/04/13/new-usmt-5-0-features-for-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx) - which is the replacement to CSIDL.

You can see people who have successfully used KnownFolderIDs [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistamigration/thread/c237e65d-ac30-4552-babd-04f01a59b370) - but it only seems to support the downloads folder...

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the default MigUSer.xml it seems like it supports the old syntax even though its supposedly replaced by Knowns Folder Id´s. I had succes using those in my custom file

%CSIDL_xxx_xxx% search for CSIDL and you will find the pathings